# Passing Object between Models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a a couple of Models like so (some code removed for simplicity)

```
class Poll extends Model
{
    public function poll()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\PollQuestion', 'pollId');
    }
}

class PollQuestion extends Model
{
    public function poll()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Poll');
    }
}
```

I then have all my routes set up, for the PollQuestion they currently look like this

```
Route::model('polls.questions', 'PollQuestion');
Route::get('/admin/polls/{id}/addquestions', [
    'as'   => 'polls.questions.create',
    'uses' => 'PollQuestionController@addQuestions'
]);
Route::post('/admin/polls/{id}/storequestions', [
    'as'   => 'polls.questions.store',
    'uses' => 'PollQuestionController@storeQuestion'
]);
```

In my PollQuestionController, to see the questions view I have

```
public function addQuestions(Request $request)
{
    $poll = Poll::where('id', '=', $request->id)->first();
    return view('poll.admin.questions', compact('poll'));
}
```

Inside this view if I dump the poll e.g.

```
{{ dd($poll) }}
```

I can see what I expect to see.  For the question form, I am doing

```
{!! Form::model(new App\PollQuestion, [
   'route' => ['polls.questions.store', $poll]
]) !!}
```

So I presume that should pass my store function the Poll Object I previously dumped.  However, in the store function, I do

```
public function storeQuestion(Request $request, Poll $poll) {
    dd($poll);
}
```

And it shows Null.  Why would this happen seeing that I am passing it the Poll Object I had previously dumped?

Thanks

Comment: why are you passing model into view ?? It's the bad way.

Answer (score 1):

You need use **Route Model Binding** correctly. According to [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-model-binding)

```php
Route::model('poll-question', App\PollQuestion::class);
Route::get('/admin/polls/{poll-question}/addquestions', [
    'as'   => 'polls.questions.create',
    'uses' => 'PollQuestionController@addQuestions'
]);
Route::post('/admin/polls/{poll-question}/storequestions', [
    'as'   => 'polls.questions.store',
    'uses' => 'PollQuestionController@storeQuestion'
]);
```

**Route::model** define a variable in the route like a **Model**. This method searches the primary key passed in the route and retrieve the Model.